# String[] vs. ArrayList as a parameter to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android-arrayadapter

I was able pass a String[] in coding a Base ArrayAdapter like so:

```
    private static String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    lv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

But I need help to do the same with a custom adapter, I get squiggly-red-underline under (this, myStringArray)

```
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, myStringArray);
    ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    view.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

it still fails even if I try to convert the String[] to an ArrayList like this:

```
    List<String> myNewStringArray = Arrays.asList(mystringArray);
```

my custom adapter looks like this:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> categories){
        super(context, 0, categories);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {...
```

Thank you

Comment: `(this, myStringArray)` is undelined - and what does IDE say?

Comment: IDE gives 3 options, (1)cast the second parameter to ArrayList<String> which when I do, the app crashes (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList), (2) change the second parameter of the method from ArrayList<String> to List<String> which when I do, the app crashes (NullPointerException:) at line         view.setAdapter(myAdapter);
(3) creat a constructor

Comment: run Debug at line view.setAdapter(myAdapter), myAdapter is populated with the original string list "a","b","c". I do not understand why it throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such constructor as you created - look [there at android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). You should provide constructor

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> categories){
    super(context, resource, categories);
}
```

and call it by `MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);`. `NullPointerException` is throwed perhaps because there is no layout with  `id == 0`, and ArrayAdapter looks for layout for single list element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was incorrect referencing of the ListView (fetching an non existed ListView) in the layout file which was declared in the setContentView method.

Thank you

Comment: You should accept this answer. It will take the question off the  unanswered questions list.